# Min value from SimpleXML Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml, min

I've tried using things like array_map, but it doesn't seem to be working since I have a mutlidimensional array made as a SimpleXML Element. The min($array) will not work either. When I print_r($array), this is how the code appears. Is there any way to grab the min value?

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 11
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 15
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I did it anyway and it works!

I created the multi dimensional array into a single dimension by running it in a foreach loop

```
foreach ($expected_seconds_array as $key => $value) { 
$value = (string) $value;
    $min_sec_array[] = $value;
}
```

Then I was able to call the min($min_sec_array); function to get the proper result. Hopefully it helps someone else out